Symfony's framework.ide config for PhpStorm and WSL
How do I set up framework.ide config value so that it properly links to files in PhpStorm, when the code is run from WSL
I've tried phpstorm://open?file=%%f&line=%%l
I used to use the substitution function &/var/www/html/>C:/web/PhpstormProjects/ before using WSL. (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#ide)
I've tried phpstorm://open?file=%%f&line=%%l&/var/www/html/>//wsl.localhost/Debian/home/web/PhpstormProjects/ without result.
What would be the solution please ?
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
...
    ide: 'phpstorm://open?file=%%f&line=%%l&/var/www/html/>\\wsl.localhost\Debian\home\web\PhpstormProjects\'


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The question seems quite clear to me. I have encountered the same problem and never found a solution....
